# How can I get the size of a WPF panel that was changed during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, width, panel

I have a `Panel` whose `Width` can be resized during runtime:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="770*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <panels:NavigationPanel x:Name="cmBar" Margin="2,2,0,2"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="220"/>
    <panels:DetailAreaPanel x:Name="detailGrid" Margin="224,2,2,2" />
</Grid>
```

When the program is closed, I want to save the new `Width` in the registry.  So the program will load to the same size next time its opened.  I have everything working except the `Width`, unless I hardcode the new `Width`.  So I would assume that my save is wrong.

`all[5] = cmBar.ActualWidth.ToString();`

`all[]` is then wrote into the registry.  No matter how the panel is resized cmBar.ActualWidth is always 220.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Instead of ActualWidth, try using the Width property. Also, is there a reason you want to write into the registry instead of a config file of some sort?

Comment: The Width property has the same problem. I dont think the registry is the problem No matter what i do i cant get Width or ActualWidth to change. Other than that its just the way i was told it needs to be done. I should add that in the code i can change these properties but i need it to be done whent he user clicks on the panel and drags it smaller.

Comment: Assuming your NavigationPanel is sizing itself to its parent, maybe you could read the ActualWidth property of the containing control instead?

Comment: I edited the question to show more of the code.  Im pretty sure it doesnt size its self to the parent, but i could be wrong.  Im very new to c# and wpf

Comment: @K1LL3r7 - I was just wondering about the registry. Nothing to do with the question :)

Comment: @Tenaciouslmpy - I figured, I wish i had a real answer other than thats what my boss said. Im currently updating from forms to WPF and the old version wrote a byte array. I was lucky enough to be able to change it to a string array, because the byte array wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aviad P. had one this right the `.Width` is what is causing the problem.  The solution is is when i load the width to load it as `.MaxWidth` This will do the resizing but allow `.ActualWidth` to have the real width of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" will allow the control to size to its parent. "Left" just sizes to itself and leaves empty space to its right.

Comment: There is another panel to its right so i will need that empty space.  The other panel is included ion the code above.  The previous answer is correct wit the problem.  ITs the .width  I need another way to set the width or read the width.

Comment: To arrange multiple elements and have them resize based on available space you should try to rely on the Panel that contains them to do layout, in this case the Grid shown with additional ColumnDefinitions.
Could you give some more detail on what it is that is causing the Width (that you want to save) to change. Are you expecting the internal content of the Panel to be changing size while running the application as opposed to a parent container (i.e. Window, Grid with GridSplitter)?

Answer (score -1):

The little piece that says `Width="220"` sets the width to 220, and that will not change unless explicitly changed from the code-behind. Are you changing the panel's width in code-behind? If not - then its width really doesn't change, and stays at 220 throughout its lifetime.

Comment: I took out that line and still when i resize the panel during runtime(click and drag) it does not change the width in either cmBar.Width or cmBar.ActualWidth.

Comment: I noticed when i load the width is loaded and set as `cmBar.Width = split;` So the answer seems to explain the problem, but does someone have a replacement for the code i use above. `Split` is parsed from the string array and `cmBar` should be set equal to it but i cant use `.width`